# Android delete a row containg 2 lists by click of an image in that row in list view

Tags: android

I have a **list view** which is populated using a **custom adapter**.The list view contains 2 lists and an image.`Format- list list image`.

I want to delete items from both the lists at the same time when that button is clicked.

I tried using `onclick` and `onitemclick` but the app crashed.

How do i delete both the lists at the same time?The list are not saved in the date base.Items are stored in an `Vector`.

What is use of index and view? 
when custom adapter extends `Base Adpater` we get a getView method which contains a parameter **position** .Is this same as index value?

```
code-holder.imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                     Index index = (Integer)  arg0.getTag();
                    if(index>=0){                        

                    prescriptionRemoval = ProgressDialog.show(AddToCartActivity.this, null, getResources().getString(R.string.prescriptionRemoval));    
                    String removeDrug=drugNameList.get(index);
                    String removePrescription=prescriptionList.get(index);  
                    String removeTotal=removeDrug+removePrescription;
                    listCheck.remove(removeTotal);
                    drugNameList.remove(index.intValue());
                    prescriptionList.remove(index.intValue());
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(DIALOG_PRESCRIPTION_REMOVAL);  
                     }
                }
            })
```

Comment: Code speaks faster then words :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.Get the position and remove both lists with the position value
and notifydatasetchanged()